# Issue with Reinstalling Eclipse After upgrading hard drive

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a programming student that recently upgraded the hard drive in my laptop through a secondary service. This service was able to save and transfer over most files, but was unable to migrate over specific program files.

When trying to reinstall Eclipse I have encountered some major issues and problems I am looking to hopefully get help with.

The first issue is that through the Eclipse installer, when trying to install eclipse it would try to look for the previously used user file and spew out 100s of error messages when this failed. A workaround to get eclipse actually installed was to change the bundle pools to off.

The second and most major issue is that eclipse does not seem to recognize or have any in build libraries, as it does not even recognize what a string is. I have the JDK and JRE installed but when trying to compile is tells me that java has been installed incorrectly (which would make sense given my hack job of installing it).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have never had so much difficulty trying to simply install something.

Comment: What platform are you on? (i.e. Windows, linux, macOS) What Eclipse version? What JDK version is installed? Note that you need to install the JDK and not the JRE.

Comment: Seems JDK not configured properly. Check that settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting .m2 folder present inside C:/Users/<User Name>/.m2 and then reinstall Eclipse.